Qt6 using Objective-C script in CPP (H) file
Normally, I use only *.h files in my c++ project as scripts are short and I don't need to really generate many files.
So, currently I have a c++ script used only in a header file. Also in there, I have some objective-c script, which currently works. However, another one does not.
I, of course, understand using objective-c in cpp file is not as easy However, it can be managed. Unfortunately, I have no experience with this just yet.
How to run the fallowing code inside cpp (header) file without having the script in separate *.mm file?
    #ifndef PERMISSION_H
    #define PERMISSION_H

    #include <QMainWindow>
    #include <QMessageBox>
    #include <QtCore/QObject>
    #include <QtCore/QMetaObject>
    #include <QUrl>
    #include <QDesktopServices>

    #if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
        #include <QtCore/qjniobject.h>
        #include <QtCore/qcoreapplication.h>
        #include <QtCore/private/qandroidextras_p.h>
    #elif defined(Q_OS_IOS)
        #include <objc/objc.h>
        #include <objc/message.h>
        #include <objc/runtime.h>
        //#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>      // this brings this error: http://www.j88.tech/appdev/macos-qt-carbon-h-warning/
        //#include <QtCore/private/qcore_map_p.h>   // if I undcomment this, error from line above changes to: "expected unqualified-id/applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/..."
    #endif

    class Permission : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        

        public:
            Permission(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

            // Photo Library
            Q_INVOKABLE bool requestMedia() {
                #if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)

                    // ANDROID: cpp script to request permission for camera galery pictures... this works fine, no need to show the code here

                #elif defined(Q_OS_IOS)

                    // iOS: objective-c script to request permission for camera galery pictures... this works fine

                    __block BOOL isAuthorized;
                    id phPhotoLibrary = (id) objc_getClass("PHPhotoLibrary");
                    SEL mediaPermission = sel_registerName("requestAuthorization:");
                    typedef void (^CompletionHandler)(int);
                    CompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(int status) {
                        switch (status) {
                            case 3: // PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized
                                qDebug() << "Permission for photo library access granted.";
                                isAuthorized = YES;
                                break;
                            case 1: // PHAuthorizationStatusDenied
                            case 2: // PHAuthorizationStatusRestricted
                                qDebug() << "Permission for photo library access denied.";
                                isAuthorized = NO;
                                break;
                            case 0: // PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined
                                qDebug() << "Permission for photo library access not determined.";
                                isAuthorized = NO;
                                break;
                        }
                    };
                    ((void (*)(id, SEL, CompletionHandler))objc_msgSend)(phPhotoLibrary, mediaPermission, completionHandler);
                    return isAuthorized;

                #endif
                return true;   // in case of Windows, where we always have proper permissions
            }


            // Photo Library - Settings
            Q_INVOKABLE void settingsMedia() {
                #if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)

                    // ANDROID: cpp script to open app settings and from here user needs to manualy navigate to permisison>camera and switch to allow (if there is possible to go deeper and open settings inside this camera permission, i would be interested to learn)... this works fine

                    QJniObject activity = QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication::context();
                    if (!activity.isValid())        { qCritical() << "Activity not valid";  return; }

                    QJniObject bundle = QJniObject::fromString("package:com.RESTOFMYBUNDLEID");
                    if (!bundle.isValid())          { qCritical() << "Bundle not valid";    return; }

                    QJniObject uri = QJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("android/net/Uri", "parse", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/net/Uri;", bundle.object<jstring>());
                    if (!activity.isValid())        { qCritical() << "Uri not valid";       return; }

                    QJniObject packageName = QJniObject::fromString("android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS");
                    if (!packageName.isValid())     { qCritical() << "Package not valid";   return; }

                    QJniObject intent = QJniObject("android/content/Intent","(Ljava/lang/String;)V", packageName.object<jstring>());
                    if (!intent.isValid())          { qCritical() << "Intent not valid";    return; }

                    intent.callObjectMethod("addCategory", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;", QJniObject::fromString("android.intent.category.DEFAULT").object<jstring>());
                    intent.callObjectMethod("setData", "(Landroid/net/Uri;)Landroid/content/Intent;", uri.object<jobject>());
                    QtAndroidPrivate::startActivity(intent.object<jobject>(), 10101);

                #elif defined(Q_OS_IOS)

                    // iOS: objective-c script to open app settings and from here user needs to manualy navigate to permisison>camera and switch to allow (same comment as above, if I can open directly in app settings in camera permission, i would like to know how)...
                    // THIS is what does not work... seems that it does not know NSURL
                    
                    // NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
                    // if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
                    //  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                    //      if (success) {
                    //          qDebug() << "Opened settings";
                    //      }
                    //  }];
                    // }

                #endif
            }
    };

    #endif // PERMISSION_H


Using only headers is a bad habit. Stick to convention.

This question is similar to: Force Header Files to Compile as C++ in Xcode. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
